# How do you use API keys in HTTP Requests?

Tags: javascript, api, endpoint

I am struggling to work out if there is a way to use an API key when trying to call data from an endpoint and if so, where would I put it?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {KEY}")

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/mlb/scores/json/AreAnyGamesInProgress')

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  }

// Send request
request.send()
```

Comment: Completely depends on the API

Comment: It depends on the endpoint. Some want it as a header, others want it as a query parameter

Comment: From [sportsdata.io](https://sportsdata.io/developers/api-documentation/nfl) - _"The API key can be passed either as a query parameter or using the following HTTP request header. `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {key}`"_

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a HTTP request header most of the times.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/mlb/scores/json/AreAnyGamesInProgress');
request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{KEY}");
request.onload = function () {
//...
};
request.send();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader